# Sparse linear algebra solvers for C#

Tags: c#, performance, memory, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

I'm working on an experimental implementation of Goldenthal et.al's inextensible cloth algorithm in C#.

First I used Math.NET Iridium to assemble and solve the matrices, but quickly replaced this with dnAnalytics since the latter allows me to reuse matrices, almost eliminating further memory allocation, which is important for real-time performance (small cloths) or iterative solving in general.

The problem is that the solvers (of primary interest are LU and Bi-CG) in dnAnalytics still allocate matrices and vectors behind the scenes, instead of reusing past allocations.

=> Are there any sparse linear algebra libraries out there that reuse memory out-of-the-box, or will I have to rewrite the code myself?

Comment: Have you found something new out? Please let us know!

Comment: Unfortunately, nope. I have not found any other free solver packages in .NET (although there are some commercial and expensive [like the MKL], but I'm not going to invest in a library I'm not going to use that much). I'm currently back'n'forth working on my own solver and sparse matrix storage, which doesn't allocate any memory per run.

Answer (score 1):

This advice may be superfluous, but when using dnAnalytics, make sure you use the Intel Math kernel library.  As tempting as the idea of a pure-C# implementation sounds, I've found the performance difference to be staggering; Dense systems were solved about one hundred times faster.

Comment: This speed difference is likely due to poor memory management by the programmer in the 'pure-C# implementation'.

Comment: Could be.  The Intel Math Kernel library supposedly contains a fair amount of hand-optimised assembly code, which will, of course, outperform most managed code.  In any case, the difference was far greater than the minor linear-factor speedup I had anticipated.